# copy simulator from one mac to another mac osx

Tags: macos, xcode, copy-paste, xcode-simulator

I'm the user with the less internet speed, one of my friend downloaded iPhone Simulator in his Xcode 4.5 to test the code in iOS 5.1, 5.0, 4.3 os too, now if I want those simulators in my mac, is there any way from there I can copy those simulators and simply paste it somewhere in my XCode.app folder that I will get those simulators in my Xcode too? --- I'm taking this as an advantage for not downloading the same thing again and save the time!

I came to know that, we can find the iPhone simulators here for XCode 4.3 or higher versions,

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/

Have anyone tried this before? or some other way to get this other than downloading.

Comment: Did you try to just copy the whole folder (starting from iPhoneSimulator.platform) over to your computer and restart Xcode?

Comment: No @patrix, I've not tried this before! that's why I'm asking if anyone had tried this or not.

Comment: What prevents you from trying it yourself and reporting back? I don't see how this could break anything, in the worst case it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @patrix told me to tried on my own self, I've do so, I got the simulator from here,

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs

and copy the simulator sdk you want to add in your xcode, and paste it on the same path as above in your mac. That's it.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, trying this to get simulators for iOS 7.1 back from my XCode 6 install to my 4.6 (old MBP17 running 10.7) ran into issues. It built OK but when launched, their Simulator didn't recognise the SDK.

Comment: @AndyDent, Surprised! it should give you an error and that's correct because iOS7 wouldn't support v.4.6.

Answer (score 2):

It's changed in xcode 6.3. The new location is `MacintoshHDD<Drive of your mac>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/...` 
You need to copy this and paste if you want to copy once downloaded simulators to other Mac.

Comment: Hello @Saad, have tried this one? I want this procedure for xcode 6.4

Comment: and also in my this mac i have 2 xcodes - 6.4 and 7.1 so where can i find 7.1's simulators for ios 9.1..... and same

Answer (score 1):

The runtime that ships with Xcode is currently (as of Xcode 8.x) co-located with the corresponding SDK `<xcode bunde>/Contents/Developer/Platforms/<simulator>.platform/Developer/SDKs`. Do not try to copy this, it is specific to the version of Xcode you have installed. This may change in the future to separate the runtime from the SDK so it is closer to the downloadable runtimes.

Downloadable runtimes are written to `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes`. These can be copied between computers just fine.

Comment: "copied ... just fine" - except unfortunately in recent macOS versions, the security gods declare: `iOS 12.4.simruntime cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified`, and the usual fixes don't seem to work because this is not an app per se that we're trying to open.